# Multiple events executing at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a method which handles different events to different button clicks. When two or more button are clicked, all events are happening at the same time instead of one at a time. This is messing up the whole program. Example

```
btn.Name = "btn1";
btn.Name = "btn2";
btn.Name = "btn3";
btn.Name = "btn4";
private void call_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (btn.Name == "btn1")
            {
                doSomething();
            }
            else if (btn.Name == "btn2")
            {
                doSomething();
            }
            else if (btn.Name == "btn3")
            {
                doSomething();
            }
            else if (btn.Name == "btn4")
            {
                doSomething();``
            }

       }
```

How can i stop this from happening and make the program execute events one at a time by the clicking order.

Comment: Is `doSomething()` doing some sort of long-running asynchronous task?

Comment: doSomething moves different images on the form depending on the button clicked.

Comment: Is this winforms, webforms, WPF or some other use of c#?  What makes you think that all of the events happen at the same time?  At least winforms UI is single-threaded, and I thought most of the other standard uses of C# were as well.

Comment: Its Windows Forms Application

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are probably clicking on the button more than one time, then if you dont' want multiple simultaneously calls, just disable the html button when clicked and renable when done.

```
<button type="button" disabled>
```

Comment: What if they use WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

Each button does something different, therefore each button deserves its own specific click handler. So solve your problem by writing the code properly by assigning a separate handler to each button.